# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'СultureGrowStage.id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, yii2

What I'm doing wrong.

The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ProductInGrowStage` LEFT JOIN `CultureGrowStage` ON `ProductInGrowStage`.`growStageId` = `CultureGrowStage`.`id` LEFT JOIN `Culture` ON `CultureGrowStage`.`cultureId` = `Culture`.`id` LEFT JOIN `Product` ON `ProductInGrowStage`.`productId` = `Product`.`id` LEFT JOIN `Vermin` ON `ProductInGrowStage`.`verminId` = `Vermin`.`id` WHERE `СultureGrowStage`.`id`='2'

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = ProductInGrowStage::find()->joinWith(['growStage.culture','product','vermin']);

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'Product.id' => $this->productId,
        'Vermin.id' => $this->verminId,
        'Culture.id'  => $this->cultureId,
        'СultureGrowStage.id' => $this->growStageId,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'doze', $this->doze])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'commentForVermin', $this->commentForVermin]);


    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: написано же, неизвестный столбец, чего тут может быть  неясного то?

Comment: Это понятно,но печему.Я же делаю JOIN на CultureGrowStage.